# Polynomials: Putnam Preparation [Reference Request]

Tags: polynomials, soft-question, contest-math, book-recommendation

A soft question:

Can anyone please share a list of books that contain the necessary theory -- and problem solving techniques -- to tackle the problems based on the topic of Polynomials that appear in the USAMO/IMO/Putnam?

Furthermore, how would you rate the difficulty level of the problems that in the book "Polynomials" by Edward Barbeau with regards to the problems that appear in these tests, i.e IMO and Putnam, especially the Putnam?

Thank you!

Comment: If you want to solve the problems on those tests, tackle the problems on those tests...

Comment: @egglog Yes, but I would like to learn certain problem solving techniques related to such questions. So, would there be a book that compiles such techniques, other than Engel's Problem Solving Techniques?

Comment: @SK2, the start of this book might help: The IMO Compendium. Search it up. I have read this book before and highly recommend this for you.